# Does ffmpeg on linux use less CPU than on W10?

Tags: ffmpeg

Does ffmpeg on linux use fewer CPU resources than ffmpeg on Win10? My focus is to reduce the cost of hardware CPU/GPU.

Comment: Try it and see!

Comment: thanks for sharing this wonderfull experience. I though this platform is for serious discussion